# How to compare objects from an array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays

I have created an object from type Cube.

```
public Cube (int lengthOfEdge, String color)
    {
        this.lengthOfEdge= lengthOfEdge;
        this.color = color;
    }
```

In addition, I created 4 different cubes and put two cubes into two different array. I want to compare the arrays to see if they are exactly the same, and by that I mean if the cube that's in arr1[1] is similar to the cube that's in arr2[1]. How do I do that?

I'm trying to use the compare method I created.

```
public boolean equals(Cube c)
    {
        if(this.getLengthOfEdge()==c.getLengthOfEdge() && this.getColor()==(c.getColor())) 
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: comparing if it is the same instance or only same values?

Comment: this.getColor().equals(c.getColor()); anyway yours is not the right way to override equals ,that's not an overrided method

Comment: same values (color is the same, length is the same)

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Reflection to compare the properties of the object. For your example, you can create a function as below and simply pass the object to the function

```
       public static  bool Compare(Cube f, Cube s)
      {
        bool returnVal = true;
        foreach (var item in f.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if(!f.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(f).Equals(s.GetType().GetProperty(item.Name).GetValue(s)))
            {
                returnVal = false;
            }
        }
        return returnVal;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare the field. if you do object = object, you are checking of their references are equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isSame = true;

foreach(int i=0; i<arr1.size(); i++) {
    if(!arr1[i].equals(arr2.[i])) {
        isSame = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Now you can choose the default `equals()` Method of `Object` or override it with your own for comparing values/hasvalues/instance/memoryadress/...
Have fun.